# Is there any Android app which will let us know the relative position of another nearby device without using GPS?

Tags: android, javascript, networking, wifi, bluetooth

I want to know if it is possible to get where exactly another nearby mobile device (e.g. Android) is with respect to my phone without using GPS. Is there any app which makes it possible to get idea of direction using bluetooth or wifi?

Comment: This sort of thing is generally done by measuring signal strength (e.g of WiFi or BT), which should decrease as you get further away. However, it gets very complicated, because just rotating your 'phone, or moving it behind an object can lower signal strength.  Also, direction is a problem, and you have to resort to triangulation and measuring the strength if signals from known devices, such as your router, to determine your location. When measuring indoors in industrial solutions, there will be many routers, not just the one that you have at home -->

Comment: I love your question, and eagerly await an answer, but I fear that it might be closed as too broad. Perhaps you could reword it, maybe asking us to recommend a tool or a library which you can link to your code, and just generally give more details of what you want? (I realize that what you want to ti “know everything”, but that sort of question doesn’t work well here, alas(). Thanks for a great question :-)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As Mawg wrote: I'm afraid we'll have to put your question on hold. This site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your question accordingly, so it can be reopened.

Comment: Rafa, please, do reword your question. I would also love to know of resources for this. For me it would be a code library or completely open source project, but you might be happy if we just named an Android app. It won't take long to edit ;-)

Comment: Thanks Mawg. Just reworded the question to ask for an Android app. Please suggest if I need to be even more specific or ask for something else instead. :)

Comment: Note that you ask for BT or WiFi – I would suggest expanding that to include the ‘phone network, unless you have a compelling reason not to. Because you will need triangulation to establish both distance and angle, you need to have some nearby, detectable, devises who's locations are known.  Do you want to confine this to a single location or country, or should it be worldwide? Fixed BT is not so common, although becoming more so with BT Low Energy -->

Comment: There are a bunch of databases of public WiFI, maybe even some private. You don’t need to be able to access them (password not required), just detect their presence & measure signal strength. There are also eNode-B cellular base stations, for ‘phones, with publicly available data; you might find an app that uses those, or public WiFi. An alternative might be to triangulate on friends who have GPS turned on, but that requires them to be in the area, with a companion app installed. I can’t think of an app that handles any of those (although I could develop one) Sorry Can you share your use case?

Comment: Thanks Mawg for all the comments. My use case is simple: People regularly find themselves in train/airport/station/cafe where they just have some time to kill and may get bored. They can see many other people around them but it is not easy to know which one of them is interesting to talk to and actually free. This kind of app can not only locate the people exactly (if they chose to be located) but also create great connections based on common interests. 
This is just one use case which made me ask this question but there can be plenty more. GPS is not reliable/accurate/available everywhere

Comment: What's the problem with using GPS?

Comment: 1. Accuracy won't be good if we are talking about a very small enclosed place like a cafe where 1m+ error can make the app pointless/wrong.


2. It may not work in all indoor scenarios.

Comment: For anyone interested in developing a solution, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604622/how-can-i-determine-my-position-by-triangulation-on-known-routers) 8.5 years ago (no wonder I had forgotten it), when such questions were still allowed on S.O. The accepted answer, http://redpin.org/ is still around. I will leave you to dig into it (and will probably do so myself :-)  "`Redpin is an open source indoor positioning system that was developed with the goal of providing at least room-level accuracy`"

Comment: Thanks for the link! No wonder you liked this question as well. ;) 
I had a look on the description and still not clear on the concept behind detecting exact position. If you understood, could you explain? 
If not, I will go through the paper and try to understand the underlying concept. Thanks again!